# tvOS 14.3 UISearchController: How to locked in display

Tags: uikit, tvos, uisearchcontroller, tvos14

Short version, is there a way to make this 14.3 look

[image]

into this prior to 14.3

[image]

Long version,
In every OS iteration the look of the UISearchController is changing. Before it only change the keyboard portion but with 14.3 it changed that the keyboard portion is on left side while the search results are on the right, which is what we don't like since we have custom view and overlays on top of it.

Any APIs to make it revert to the previous iteration, that is the keyboard are all within one horizontal line and search results on bottom, and stay that way forever?

Here's the code for the integration. The 14.3 UI look did mess up the app overall.

```
_searchResults = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:_searchResults];
_searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
_searchController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
_searchController.searchBar.placeholder = @"TV Shows, Movies, Keywords";
_searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true;
 
_searchContainer = [[UISearchContainerViewController alloc] initWithSearchController:_searchController];
_navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_searchContainer];     
[_navController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:_navController];
[self.view addSubview:_navController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no code to change keyboard looking but it's simply changed on your device setting:

`Settings>General>Keyboard = Auto`

but you can changed to "Linear" or "Grid"[image]

for more information see the video:
[Discover search suggestions for Apple TV](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10634/)